# How can I break the loop and test the loop gain for a capacitive opamp?

Tags: analog, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

Here is an opamp with a capacitive feedback network
[image]

I have tried two methods to break the loop and obtain the frequency response for the loop.

Method 1

Use a large inductor to break the loop at high frequencies and a large cap to provide the AC input at high frequencies. Test signal is applied at Vt and the response is obtained at Vr.

Schematic

[image]

The frequency response is "wierd"
[image]

Method 2
Remove the large cap

Schematic
[image]

The frequency response looks "normal"
[image]

So which of the above methods is a correct way to break the loop? If both are wrong, what is the right method to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder what the parameters of your Op-Amp are, because I can hardly think of any real device that plays nice in the femtofarad range.

Comment: @Janka It is a two-stage opamp implemented in nanometer technology. Both the W and L are in nano range.

Comment: Beware that with no DC path to the input this circuit will not behave the way you expect.  A practical version needs something like a high value feedback resistor.  And even beside that, your intentional capacitances are so tiny that stray sources may dominate.   Essentially the question is nonsense except perhaps in finding the ways in which your model differs from reality.

Comment: Are you suggesting that such an op-amp exists ? The very absence of DC feedback breaks the rules of op-amp theory.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Sorry if I have asked a wrong question. I would suppose such a circuit exist. For example, should a switched capacitor opamp be in a similar topology?

Comment: I've never used those switched capacitor devices so can't comment on that. Do you perhaps envisage an AC amplifier that's DC stable with huge gain and a differential input ?

Answer (score 1):

Your second circuit will alter the bias conditions and almost certainly is saturating the amplifier and preventing normal operation.

You need to inject the test signal in such a way that the DC bias conditions are maintained.

You don't show any DC bias for the amplifier - how is that managed? Is there internal DC feedback that is not shown?

Comment: The DC bias is 0.4V at  both Vin- and Vin+.

Comment: Is that good enough to ensure the correct bias conditions? Normally there would be DC feedback from the output to do that. You should probably check the voltage at the output node to ensure that the DC bias is correct.

Comment: No.  Vin- only has a deterministic DC level in the third version where you "short out" the feedback path by overriding it with the "infinite effort" of a theoretical *voltage source* reducing the entire mess to a simple *comparator*.  What is your actual goal here?  What are you trying to accomplish by playing with this impractical circuit?

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. What I am thinking of is a switched capacitor, similar to a comparator structure. Maybe I should add a resistor in parallel with the 0.1pF cap to establish a correct DC biasing.

Comment: @Underdog *The DC bias is 0.4V at both Vin- and Vin+.* You don't show that. There must be some connections for the bias path. It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The **requirement** is: Breaking the loop at a point where this opening does not change (a) the operating point and (b) the loading conditions at the opening.

I suppose you are using an ideal opamp model - as far as input/output resistances and bias conditions are concerned. Otherwise, the whole circuit would not work at all (missing DC feedback).

Therefore, the most simple and logical testpoint to open the loop is the opamps output node. (In this case, you do not need an inductor).